# Looking for binary class datasets with high class imbalance, that also have intra-class imbalance in the minority class

Tags: classification, class-imbalance, beginner, smote

Newbie question alert...

For a college project I want to compare a few variants of SMOTE in terms of how much they improve classification of the minority class, over using random oversampling.

I have a specific interest in the idea that the minority class may contain small disjuncts that may themselves exhibit imbalance within the class.

I am already looking at the credit card fraud dataset on Kaggle (https://www.kaggle.com/mlg-ulb/creditcardfraud)

Can anyone please point me towards other datasets that have the following kinds of properties:

- a reasonably large number of examples (ideally at least a few thousand)
- have only two class labels
- are highly imbalanced, i.e. the minority class is severely under-represented
- ideally the minority examples would have some intra-class imbalance too

Or even better, is there any kind of good search tool out there for finding datasets based on these kinds of characteristics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `imblearn.datasets` package (documentation [is here](https://imbalanced-learn.org/stable/datasets/index.html)) has a function called `fetch_datasets()` which is described as:

> `fetch_datasets` allows to fetch 27 datasets which are imbalanced and binarized

I do not know them in sufficient depth to know whether they meet all four of the criteria you've listed, but these may be a good first place to start with.

Comment: Thanks - that just might do the trick!